# Getting individual count of insert and update using merge statement - C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am using `MERGE` command to upsert rows (using dapper ORM), and I would like to get the count of individual insert and update separately. I have dumped the merge actions to a temp table to query later. The rows are getting correctly upserted when I check against the database, however I'm not able to get the count of each action

Here I have added a list containing 3 items via C#, and the merge statement correctly adds them.

[image]

On inspecting the result that stores the operation (insert or update) I see count as 1 instead of 3

[image]

The temp table used in the merge statement when executed in SSMS using a similar source and destination table returns the table with correct count:

[image]

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thank you.

I'll paste the C# code for reference:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }
}

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>> UpsertProductCostAsync()
    {
        var products = new List<Product> 
                    {
                        new Product {ProductID = 1, ProductName = "Tea", Rate = 10},
                        new Product {ProductID = 2, ProductName = "Coffee", Rate = 20},
                        new Product {ProductID = 3, ProductName = "Muffin", Rate = 30}
                    };

        var mergeStatement = @"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##MergeActions
                               CREATE TABLE ##MergeActions ([MergeAction] VARCHAR(10))
                               INSERT INTO ##MergeActions ([MergeAction])
                                   SELECT [MergeAction]
                                   FROM
                                       (MERGE [dbo].[Products] AS target 
                                        USING (VALUES (@ProductID, @ProductName, @Rate)) AS source (ProductID, ProductName, Rate) 
                                              ON (target.ProductID = source.ProductID)
                                        WHEN MATCHED THEN
                                            UPDATE
                                                SET target.ProductName = source.ProductName,
                                                    target.Rate = source.Rate
                                        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                                            INSERT ([ProductID],[ProductName], [Rate]) 
                                            VALUES (source.ProductID, source.ProductName, source.Rate)
                                        OUTPUT $action AS MergeAction) MergeOutput;
                                        ";

        _con.Open();
        var rowsAffected = await _con.ExecuteAsync(mergeStatement, products);
        var operationsWithCount = await _con.QueryAsync(@"SELECT [MergeAction], COUNT(*) as [Count]
FROM ##MergeActions  
GROUP BY MergeAction;");

        var result = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

        foreach (var o in operationsWithCount)
        {
            result.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(o.MergeAction, o.Count));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

SQL Server table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
   ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
   ProductName VARCHAR(100),
   Rate int
)
```

Comment: Using a global temp table for this is a bad idea; this easily conflicts with other actions. You can declare a table variable (or local temp table, I don't recall if table vars are allowed for `OUTPUT`) in the batch that performs the `MERGE`, select it at the end, and use `QueryAsync` to do everything in one delimited batch. This avoids any potential problems with parallel merges overwriting results.

Comment: You have an async method containing two tasks that share a _con variable that's defined externally. Likely you have other async tasks closing and opening this connection and that will cause the global temp table to go out of scope. You'd probably be better served consuming the merge's output directly in a DataTable instead of a global temp table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest starting with a table-value parameter in SQL Server. That'll let you pass in your list of products and get the result in the same SQL command.

```sql
CREATE TYPE TVP_Product AS TABLE
(
    ProductID integer not null,
    ProductName varchar(100) not null,
    Rate int not null
);
```

Your C# could then be:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>> UpsertProductCostAsync()
{
    var products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product {ProductID = 1, ProductName = "Tea", Rate = 10},
                new Product {ProductID = 2, ProductName = "Coffee", Rate = 20},
                new Product {ProductID = 3, ProductName = "Muffin", Rate = 30}
            };

    // one approach to transforming a collection to a datatable.
    // you could find / create an extension method to do this more succintly
    var productsDt = new DataTable();
    productsDt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(int));
    productsDt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
    productsDt.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(int));

    foreach (var product in products)
        productsDt.Rows.Add(product.ProductID, product.ProductName, product.Rate);

    var mergeStatement = @"
            
MERGE INTO [dbo].[Products] AS target 
USING (select ProductId, ProductName, Rate from @products) as source 
ON (target.ProductID = source.ProductID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET target.ProductName = source.ProductName,
    target.Rate = source.Rate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([ProductID],[ProductName], [Rate]) 
VALUES (source.ProductID, source.ProductName, source.Rate)
OUTPUT $action AS MergeAction;

";

    _con.Open();

    var actions = await _con.QueryAsync<string>(mergeStatement, 
        new { 
            products = productsDt.AsTableValuedParameter("TVP_Product") 
        }
    );

    var results = actions
        .GroupBy(x => x, (y, z) =>
            new Tuple<string, int>(y, z.Count()))
        .ToList();

    return results;
}
```